# How can I configure syslog.conf file, to log iptables messages in a separate file?

Tags: linux, iptables, syslog

How can I configure `/etc/syslog.conf` file in order to save log information about `iptables` in a specific file.

I want to save these information separately, so I can extract what I want easily and rapidly.

Comment: Are you using syslog.conf or rsyslog.conf?

Answer (score 13):

#### syslog

Take a look in the man page for `iptables`. It shows a target called `LOG` which can do what you want.

#### Example

1. Set the logging level for `LOG` to 4.

   ```
   # DROP everything and Log it
   iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-level 4
   iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
   ```
2. Configure `syslog.conf` to write these messages to a separate file.

   ```
   # /etc/syslog.conf
   kern.warning     /var/log/iptables.log
   ```
3. Restart syslogd.

   *Debian/Ubuntu*

   ```
   $ sudo /etc/init.d/sysklogd restart
   ```

   *Fedora/CentOS/RHEL*

   ```
   $ sudo /etc/init.d/syslog restart
   ```

**NOTE:** This method of logging is called fixed priorities. They are either numbers or names (1,2,3,4,..) or (DEBUG, WARN, INFO, etc.).

#### rsyslog

If by chance you're using `rsyslog`, you can create a property based filter like so:

```
# /etc/rsyslog.conf
:msg, contains, "NETFILTER"       /var/log/iptables.log
:msg, contains, "NETFILTER"     ~
```

Then add thils switch to your iptables rules that you want to log:

```
–log-prefix NETFILTER
```

As an alternative you could also log the messages using this type of property filter:

```
:msg, startswith, "iptables: " -/var/log/iptables.log
& ~
:msg, regex, "^\[ *[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\] iptables: " -/var/log/iptables.log
& ~
```

**NOTE:** This 2nd method doesn't require any changes to `iptables`.

#### References

- [Force iptables to log messages to a different log file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/force-iptables-to-log-messages-to-a-different-log-file.html)
- [Logging iptables messages with rsyslog](http://blog.stalkr.net/2009/10/logging-iptables-messages-with-rsyslog.html)

Comment: In this case, inforamtion will be saved in `/var/log/iptables` and also in `/var/log/messages`.  I want only one copy from this data in `iptables.log`

Comment: I added my own answer to also cover Abid's question, plus the missing logrotate config. the "stop" or "& ~" prevents the messages from continuing down rsyslog's rules to get to /var/log/messages also.

Answer (score 6):

This assumes your firewall already makes logs, as any sane firewall should. For some examples, it requires an identifiable message, such as "NETFILTER" in slm's example.

make a file in rsyslog.d

```
vim /etc/rsyslog.d/10-firewall.conf
```

This works in CentOS 7. I don't know how to verify that it came from the firewall other than looking for IN and OUT... CentOS is weird. Don't use this unless the next version doesn't work.

```
# into separate file and stop their further processing
if  ($msg contains 'IN=' and $msg contains 'OUT=') \
then {
    -/var/log/firewall
    & ~
}
```

This works in CentOS 7 and checks for the message content too (replace "Shorewall" with whatever you have in your -j LOG rule's message):

```
# into separate file and stop their further processing
if  ($msg contains 'Shorewall') and \
    ($msg contains 'IN=' and $msg contains 'OUT=') \
then {
    -/var/log/firewall
    & ~
}
```

This works in others (Ubuntu, Debian, openSUSE). And this is the best way to do it. No searching for strings in the message:

```
# into separate file and stop their further processing
if  ($syslogfacility-text == 'kern') and \\
($msg contains 'IN=' and $msg contains 'OUT=') \\
then    -/var/log/firewall
    &   ~
```

And here is what a default openSUSE machine has (which I think every distro should have and is missing) (difference seems to be only "stop" instead of "& ~"; not all systems support both syntaxes):

```
if  ($syslogfacility-text == 'kern') and \
    ($msg contains 'IN=' and $msg contains 'OUT=') \
then {
    -/var/log/firewall
    stop
}
```

And for all of the above, don't forget a logrotate.d file too:

```
vim /etc/logrotate.d/firewall
```

containing:

```
/var/log/firewall {
    rotate 7
    size 500k
    postrotate
        # before using this, run the command yourself to make sure 
        # it is right... the daemon name may vary
        /usr/bin/killall -HUP rsyslogd
    endscript
}
```